# How does one prove that $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How does one prove that $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$?

A big problem is that I never even know where to start with proofs.

$\Rightarrow (x \in A \land x\in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \\
\Rightarrow (x \in A) \land (x \in B \lor x \notin B)\\
\Rightarrow (x \in A) \land true \\
\Rightarrow (x \in A)  $

When you prove these theory you need to show the way and the return. However its only going but i dont know how to make the turn. In which case you need another way to prove the return. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to show each element on one side also resides in the other side.

Comment: Let x∈(A∩B) v x∈(A-B).
Then x∈ A and x ∈ B ....

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Try drawing a Venn Diagram

Comment: I find for proofs about sets to do an element be element proof.  If $x \in A$ then either $x \in B$ or it isnt.  if $x \in B$ then $x \in A \cap B$ if it isn't than $x \in A-B$ so $x \in (A\cap B)\cup A- B$ so $A \subset (A\cap B)\cup A- B$.  If $x \in (A\cap B)\cup A- B$ either $x \in A \cap B \subset A$ or $x \in A-B \subset A$.  Either way $x \in A$.  So $ (A\cap B)\cup A- B \subset A$.  So $A =  (A\cap B)\cup A- B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing is basically translate the definitions into corresponding
logical statement and verify them. For any element $x$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&x \in (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)\\
\color{blue}{\text{ defn. of union } \cup } 
 \iff & x \in ( A\cap B ) \lor x \in (A \setminus B)\\
\color{blue}{\text{ defn of intersection } \cap \text{ and set complement }\setminus} \iff & ( x \in A \land x \in B ) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B)\\
\color{blue}{\text{distributive law of logical or } \lor \text{ and logical and } \land}\iff & x \in A \land ( x \in B \lor x \notin B )\\
\color{blue}{\text{law of excluded middle}}\iff & x \in A \land \verb/true/\\
\color{blue}{\text{defn of logical and } \land }\iff & x \in A
\end{align}
$$
Since this is true for all element $x$, by definition of set equality, we have $$(A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B) = A$$

For a verbal proof, just read out the statements on the right in English. Replace every occurrence of the symbol $\land$  by word 'and' and  symbol $\lor$ by word 'or'. For example, the first step

$$x \in (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)  \iff x \in ( A\cap B ) \lor x \in (A \setminus B)$$

becomes:

- $x$ belongs to $(A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$ means
  $x$ belongs to $(A\cap B)$ OR $x$ belongs to $(A \setminus B)$.

For the remaining steps, the translation of the logical statement to reasoning is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Hints/sketch:

- Two sets $S$ and $T$ are equal if $S \subset T$ and $T \subset S$.
- Assume $A \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$. Let $x \in A$. Show that $x$ also belongs to the set on the right.
- Do the same thing in the other direction.